# Make MultiViews work even if the requested file does exist

Tags: apache-2.2, content-negotiation

From the [Apache 2 docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html):

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for `/some/dir/foo`, if `/some/dir` has MultiViews enabled, and `/some/dir/foo` does ***not*** exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named `foo.*`, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files...

Is there any way to make MultiViews do its magic even if the requested file ***does*** exist? For example I might have these files:

- foo.html
- foo.html.gz

When `/foo.html` is requested, I want to return `foo.html.gz` if the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` 
header is sent.

MultiViews can do this fine, but you have to either request just `/foo` or rename `foo.html` to `foo.html.en` (which is hackish, and doesn't work if you request from a non-English browser).

Answer (score 0):

This will make it load the .gz file if gzip compression is accepted. Otherwise it'll skip this rule and just load the normal html file.

Note: You must have the mod_rewrite module installed to use this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.html.gz [NC,L,QSA]
```